# Tracking resource url on google tag manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a simple script resource URL on my web site. It is a javascript file. My members insert external resource link on their home pages as below and downloads this resource.

```
<script src="My-URL"></script>
```

I want to track these downloads on google tag manager. When I search there are examples about file downloads with click event. But I couldn't find an example for my case.